# Many to many self reference in Sequelize in twitter like web-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, many-to-many, sequelize.js

I'm trying to build a blog web-application as an excercise to understand ORM and Sequelize in particular. I managed quite easily to form relations between posts and comments and users and posts. No problems there. The horror begins when I try to link users to users as followers and users to users as followeds. I also want it to be possible to follow yourself.

I have tried something like this:

```
  const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    firstName: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    lastName: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    activated: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
    }
  })
User.belongsToMany(User, {as: "Follower", foreignKey: "FollowerId", through: "Follower_Followeds"})
User.belongsToMany(User, {as: "Followed", foreignKey: "FollowedId", through: "Follower_Followeds"})
```

And to set the relations:

```
app.post("/followhandler", function(req, res) {
    let userId = req.session.userId
    let followId = req.body.followId

    User.findById(userId)
    .then( currentUser => {
        User.findById(followId)
        .then( follows => {
            currentUser.addUser(follows)
        })
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e)) 
})
```

But the Follower_Followeds table will simply not get updated.
I've also tried to skip the many to many implementation of Sequelize by creating a separate table and adding the relations manually:

```
const FollowerFollowed = sequelize.define('followerFollowed', {
  followedId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },

  followerId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  }  
})

//define Users
  const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    firstName: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    lastName: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    activated: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
    }
  })
```

And the handler:

```
app.post("/followhandler", function(req, res) {
    let userId = req.session.userId
    let followId = req.body.followId

    FollowerFollowed.create( {
        followerId: userId,
        followedId: followId
    })
    .then( rel => console.log(rel))
    .catch(e => console.log(e)) 
})
```

But I'm getting the following error in this case:

> TypeError: val.replace is not a function
>       at Object.SqlString.escape (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sql-string.js:61:15)
>       at Object.escape (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:978:22)
>       at Object.insertQuery (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:299:28)
>       at QueryInterface.insert (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-interface.js:497:33)
>       at . (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance.js:679:56)
>       at tryCatcher (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:510:31)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:567:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:612:10)
>       at Promise._settlePromises (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:691:18)
>       at Async._drainQueue (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
>       at Async._drainQueues (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
>       at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:649:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:622:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:594:5) TypeError: val.replace is not a function
>       at Object.SqlString.escape (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sql-string.js:61:15)
>       at Object.escape (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:978:22)
>       at Object.insertQuery (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:299:28)
>       at QueryInterface.insert (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-interface.js:497:33)
>       at . (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance.js:679:56)
>       at tryCatcher (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:510:31)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:567:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:612:10)
>       at Promise._settlePromises (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:691:18)
>       at Async._drainQueue (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
>       at Async._drainQueues (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
>       at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/home/piepongwong/Documents/NYCDA/blog/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:649:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:622:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:594:5)

Answer (score 2):

When you create the M:M association you use `as: 'Follower'` and `as: 'Followed'` attributes. It influences the way you can add/set/delete associations between users. Method to add followed user to other user is now called `addFollowed` and would be used in exactly the same way you did it.

```js
User.findById(userId).then( currentUser => {
    User.findById(followId).then( follows => {
        currentUser.addFollowed(follows); // notice the difference here
    });
});
```

The same occurs if you want to add follower to given user - then you would use `addFollower` method.

Moreover, in your second solution you have made a mistake while creating the associating Model. In the `User` model you have defined associations via foreign keys `FollowerId` and `FollowedId`, however in the `FollowerFolloweds` definition you have created `followerId` and `followedId`, so those two do not match each other - you need to keep the names consistent.

**EDIT**

According to the documentation in the `belongsToMany` relation, the `as` attribute should be named as plural, so in your case you should name those `as: 'Followers'` and `as: 'Followeds'` (the second one seems a little strange). Sequelize singularizes those values itself, however you can define it by yourself using object `as: { singular: 'Follower', plural: 'Followers' }`

> The alias of this association. If you provide a string, it **should be plural**, and **will be singularized using node.inflection**. If you want to control the singular version yourself, provide an object with **plural** and **singular** keys.